# how to make langton's ant move a step in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ant

i just started studying computer science and got stuck on programming langton's ant.
my ant needs to move a step roughly like this

ant on white facing :east >>> row+1, south >>> column-1, west >>> row-1, north >>> column+1

ant on black facing :east >>> row-1, south >>> column+1, west >>> row+1, north >>> column-1

```
def ant_coordinates(ant_row, ant_col, orientation):
    color = orig_grid[ant_row][ant_col]
    if color == 'white':
        orientation == 'East'
        ant_row += 1
        orientation == 'South'
        ant_col -= 1
    return ant_row, ant_col, orientation
```

my thing adds one to the row part when i put south as the orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing for equality, but not doing anything with it, with those `==`. What you need is something like:

```
def ant_coordinates(ant_row, ant_col, orientation):
    color = orig_grid[ant_row][ant_col]
    if color == 'white':
        if orientation == 'East':
            ant_row += 1
        elif orientation == 'South':
            ant_col -= 1
    return ant_row, ant_col, orientation
```

I'm not sure what the actual behavior of this function is supposed to be, but what it will do is:

If color is not white, just return all of the parameters unchanged.

If color is white and orientation is east, return all of the parameters with row += 1.

If color is white and orientation is south, return all of the parameters with col -= 1.

If color is white and orientation is other, return all parameters unchanged. You can obviously extend this function to add functionality for other directions.

What your code does now is:

```
def ant_coordinates(ant_row, ant_col, orientation):
    color = orig_grid[ant_row][ant_col]
    if color == 'white': # goes in here if color is white
        orientation == 'East' # returns True or False, value not used anywhere
        ant_row += 1 # always increments row if color is white
        orientation == 'South' # returns True or False, value not used anywhere
        ant_col -= 1 # always decrements col if color is white
    return ant_row, ant_col, orientation
```

Hope this helps! `==` is just a comparison, it doesn't imply an `if`.

Comment: I think (without looking at the problem) that the OP might want "=" instead for `orientation ==`.

Comment: i do not understand what you said. i need my ant to move 90degrees to the right and step 1 box forward if on white tile, and move 90degrees to the left and step 1 box forward if on black. help?